# How do I determine the height of a div that has yet to be displayed on the page

Tags: javascript, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the tabs feature of the twitter bootstrap v2.2.2 API within divs being displayed using twitter modal (again, v2.2.2 of the bootstrap). The problem is, when I do this the modal dialog changes shape and size as the tabs change.

I have been looking at trying to set the size of the div that wraps the tab panes by interrogating those tab panes and setting the outer div to the maximum size and width encountered from the panes. Problem is, whatever I do I always seem to be unable to determine the size of those panes (I assume because they have yet to be displayed?).

My layout (roughly)...

```
<div id="ClientEditPanel" class="modal hide" role="dialog">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Client details</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a class="active" data-toggle="tab" href="#ClientEditPanel_Tab_Personal">Personal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ClientEditPanel_Tab_Profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ClientEditPanel_Tab_Other" data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="ClientEditPanel_Tabs" class="tab-content">
      <div id="ClientEditPanel_Tab_Personal" class="tab-pane active">
        ...
      </div>
      <div id="ClientEditPanel_Tab_Profile" class="tab-pane">
        ...
      </div>
      <div id="ClientEditPanel_Tab_Other" class="tab-pane">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer form-actions">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>

</div>
```

this is further supported by the following CSS...

```
.tab-content {
  overflow: auto;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane, {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active, {
  display: block;
}
```

I am trying to get the panes as follows...

```
$.each($(".tab-pane"), function () {
  ...
});
```

*In theory* it should then be as simple as setting the width of the parent div to the width of the widest child and the height of the parent div to the height of the tallest child. I want to measure ClientEditPanel_Tab_Personal, ClientEditPanel_Tab_Profile and ClientEditPanel_Tab_Other and set the maximums on ClientEditPanel_Tabs.

Through debugging, I can confirm that my selector is bringing back the right elements "this" clearly represents my first tab on the first pass through the iterator. Having ascertained that though, whichever property of the div that I interrogate is always null or zero. I have tried the following properties of "this"...

- clientHeight
- clientWidth
- scrollHeight
- scrollWidth
- innerHeight
- innerWidth
- outerHeight
- outerWidth
- style.height
- style.pixelHeight
- offsetHeight

and probably a few more that I have not listed.

Does anybody have any further ideas that I might achieve what I am looking for. I am sure it can be done as I know that JQuery.dialog can automatically size the dialog to the content (including when combined with JQuery.tabs), but I am too far down the road with the twitter bootstrap to change now.

Thanks.

Comment: put scrollbar on the wrapper

Comment: Elements hidden with `display:none` (what jQuery usually does) behave as if they where not even in the DOM at all, so they don't have any dimensions. Another method of hiding the element would have to be used (visibility, positioning of the screen) to be able to ask for dimensions.

Comment: @EL: Care to expand on that?

Comment: @CBroe: I have checked for that and you are right in as much as 2 of 3 "tab pane" divs are display:none, but the 1st pane (and the one that I have been looking at) is display:block. Thanks though.

Comment: You could put the div in a zero-height container with `overflow:hidden;`. The div would render and have dimensions, but it wouldn't affect the page.

Comment: @MattCoughlin: I am not sure I follow. I tried setting the parent tab to height:0; width:0; overflow:hidden and still I can find no valid height or width property on the parent or the child. I figure this is probably because I have gotten the wrong end of what you are suggesting - any chance of an example? I will update my question with some source.

Comment: @MartinRobins: In general, when you get a value of 0 for the size of an element, that indicates that the element has not been rendered. To get a size, the element will have to be rendered, but in such a way that the user doesn't see it, and it doesn't cause scroll bars to appear on the page (from the additional content being rendered). Not certain now if my first comment was the right suggestion (may have spoken too quickly).

Answer (score 1):

The height and width properties of an element aren't set until the element is rendered in HTML. You can push the container to be off the page, render the content, do some adjustments and then move the content back to the screen. From my personal experience, I would just render the output and then on document ready (jQuery) I would make the adjustment to the page.  This should happen very fast and I haven't noticed any adverse affects as long as the number of elements is fairly small.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read dimensions unless it is in DOM. As @Kalpers suggested, render it outside viewport (e.g. append to `<body>` and have `position:absolute; top: -9999px` or append anywhere else but add `visibility:hidden`, then get element dimensions.